# Vim cursor position on new split window

Tags: vim

The default behaviour keeps the cursor on the original split window, so I have to press ctrl+w hjkl to switch to the new one. How can I set vim to to this automatically for me, whenever i open a new split pane?

Comment: how did you give the `(v)sp` cmd? here cursor automatically goes to the new split.. e.g. `:sp another.file`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you `:split filename`, the new window (containing `filename`) will be active. It's just that your perception of what is "original" differs from Vim's behavior when you `:split` / `<C-w>s` the current window into two.

You can influence Vim's behavior (for both same-buffer and different-file splits) with the following options:

```
:set splitbelow
:set splitright
```

If you just want to change the behavior for same-buffer splits, you have to override the default `<C-w>s` command with a mapping; there, you can use the `:belowright split` command to influence the behavior without modifying the mentioned options.