# vim split window: Focus new window

Tags: vim

I have mapped for convenience:

```
" this is a ctrl + backslash binding to vsplit
nmap <C-\> :vsplit<CR>
" this is a ctrl + hyphen binding to hsplit
nmap <C-_> :split<CR>
```

This is good but needs one more final touch to behave the way I want which is that it should focus the newly created window so I can immediately open up whatever file I want in it using traditional `:e` or CtrlP plugin. As it is now, doing that is going to navigate from the original window which is slightly disorienting.

How can I get `:split` and `:vsplit` to auto-focus the newly created vim window?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Vim cursor position on new split window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15968880/vim-cursor-position-on-new-split-window)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

When I open the new split my cursor is automatically focused in the new window by default. What you probably don't realise is that the new vertical split is put on the left and the new horizontal split is put on the top.

To open new splits on the right or on the bottom of the screen add the following to your vimrc.

```
set splitbelow
set splitright
```

Comment: Fancy. That's not easy to figure out just by using `:[v]split`.

Comment: But easy to figure out when you do `:vnew`.

Comment: Setting `splitbelow` and `splitright` is all fine and dandy, but I'm not sure if I can get used to `:h` now opening a split below as well. Would it be possible to let just `:h` split "above"?

Comment: I just noticed that too! `:h` shows up at the bottom. which I'm fine with.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if it's 100% flexible and works in every situation, but you could combine it with a move cursor to another window command, such as <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>w</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd>.

```
nnoremap <C-\> <C-w>v<C-w>w
```

- `<C-w>v` - like `:vsplit`
- `<C-w>w` - move cursor to window below/right of the current one

Comment: This is not a bad idea though I do believe it will not always go to the right window. The doc doesn't seem to indicate that CTRL-W_W has a `:` command equivalent, which is weird

Comment: @StevenLu Yeah, that could be troublesome depending on how you want to do your splits. I actually have a bind for something similar, but `splitbelow` and `splitright` seems to be a better solution.

Comment: @StevenLu if you type `:h split` the two lines above it show the the normal mode commands.

Comment: @FDinoff, well that wasn't where I found the answer to "what `:` command goes with CTRL-W_W", but I did find it after scrolling down a ways, it is `:wincmd w` that will issue the same functionality.